# zsh: command not found: git-flow

Tags: command-line, git, zsh

I want to use git-flow on my Ubuntu machine but I am getting `zsh: command not found: git-flow`

Steps I followed are:

1. Installed git-flow,

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git-flow
   ```
2. After installing I use git-flow to initialize on my project

   ```
   git-flow init
   ```

   But I get bellow error

   ```
   zsh: command not found: git-flow
   ```

Please help me to use git-flow on my Ubuntu machine

Answer (score 1):

[git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) is a git extension, not a separate command. [Adds hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to normal `git`. Try

```
git flow init
```

You can list files from the package with `dpkg -L git-flow`.

If `git-flow` is not installed you'll get

```
$ git flow init
git: 'flow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar commands are
        reflog
        show
```

Check also [git-flow oh-my-zsh plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/git-flow).